# Storing information in java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, set

I want to store information, String username, String password and String loginType.

When a login is attempted, I want to find if the username exists, then verify the password and return the loginType.

What is the best type of collection for storing this?

What i need to be able to do is --> When i try to add details I first must check if the username is already there. If there is no match, my details will save, if the username already exists the data wont save.

I also need to search. I want to be able to find the username. and then verify if i have a password match and return the type

The order of these items does not matter.

What is the best type of collection for storing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a collection; I'd create an object called Credentials:

```
package security;

public class Credentials {
    private final String username;
    private final String password; 
    private final String type;

    public Credentials(String u, String p, String t) {
        this.username = u;
        this.password = p;
        this.type = t;    
    }
}

// you add the rest.
```

Comment: -1 You've only read half the question.  He also needs to look up by username.

Comment: Then use a `HashMap<String, Credentials>`.

Comment: Also, your class name should be `Credential` to follow standard Java naming conventions. Your hashmap would then look like `Hashmap<String, Credential> credentials;`

Comment: Credential, Credentials - whatever.  Maybe there's authorizations to add in as well, in which case plural is perfectly correct.  I did a simple case to steer the conversation.  As for half the question, at least I offered something besides judgemental comments.

Comment: Your thanks are very nice, but I'd prefer that you accept the answer if it helped.  It's good for me, good for you.

Answer (score 0):

With whatever you have specified you don't need a collection initially; what you need is model your data into an object.

I would recommend `@duffymo` example with 3 members inside a class:

```
public class Credentials {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String loginType;
}
```